# Userform opens when selecting command button. How do I make data input into the textboxes in the form insert onto row in separate sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to create a UserForm which will open when I select a command button.  The purpose of it is to capture data from a selected row concerning a "tour" - i.e. the tour code, start date and end date, and then for me to "split" the tour, for which I need to enter new tour codes, start dates and end dates.

I need the data from the form to go into a separate sheet (called "splits"), so that I have a record of the original tour details, and the new tour details in one sheet. But I get a Run-Time error '1004' (Application-defined or object-defined error) when I try to run the macro. I'm new to VBA and I don't know what I've done wrong!

This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me
        .OriginalTourCode.Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "A").Value
        .OriginalStartDate.Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "B").Value
        .OriginalEndDate.Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "C").Value
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub SplitTourCommand_Click()

Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Splits")

erow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0)
    Cells(erow, 1) = OriginalTourCode.Text
    Cells(erow, 2) = OriginalStartDate.Text
    Cells(erow, 3) = OriginalEndDate.Text
    Cells(erow, 4) = NewTourCode1.Text
    Cells(erow, 5) = NewStartDate1.Text
    Cells(erow, 6) = NewEndDate1.Text
    Cells(erow, 7) = NewTourCode2.Text
    Cells(erow, 8) = NewStartDate2.Text
    Cells(erow, 9) = NewEndDate2.Text
    Cells(erow, 10) = ReasonForSplit.Text


End Sub

Private Sub CloseCommand_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub
```

The Userform Intitialise section automatically fills in the first three cells of the UserForm, and then I'll use the form to enter the new data.

The Close command section is just a separate button on the form to exit out.

How to I get the form, when I click the "split tour" command button, to enter the data into the next empty row of the "splits" sheet?

Thanks so much in advance for helping.

Comment: What value does `erow` contain?  (And what data type has it been defined as?)  You can use `Debug.Print` to output it to the Immediate Window

Comment: As I say, I'm new to VBA so I don't know what you mean by what value is erow? I thought that string of code just meant that it would find the next empty row on the "Splits" sheet? Where do I put Debug.print ?

Comment: If you put, for example `Debug.Print erow` after the `erow = ..` row, then it will output the value for you to look at - but, you would actually get an error before that (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
erow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

There were 2 errors in your code.  First, the command is `xlUp`, not `x1Up` - "xl" is short for "Excel", not "X One" - this is a perfect example of why you should almost always use [`Option Explicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement)

Second: your code as-is will try to put the `.Value` from the cell into untyped variable `erow` - since the cell is blank (as the cell *below* the last cell with data), this means that `erow` will **always** be `0`.  And Row 0 does not exist to put data into.

Instead, by using `Range.Row`, we get the next row number to insert data on

Answer (score 0):

You were so close

```
Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Splits")

erow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0)
    ws.Cells(erow, 1) = OriginalTourCode.Text
    ws.Cells(erow, 2) = OriginalStartDate.Text
    ws.Cells(erow, 3) = OriginalEndDate.Text
    ws.Cells(erow, 4) = NewTourCode1.Text
    ws.Cells(erow, 5) = NewStartDate1.Text
    ws.Cells(erow, 6) = NewEndDate1.Text
    ws.Cells(erow, 7) = NewTourCode2.Text
    ws.Cells(erow, 8) = NewStartDate2.Text
    ws.Cells(erow, 9) = NewEndDate2.Text
    ws.Cells(erow, 10) = ReasonForSplit.Text


End Sub
```

Comment: I'm still getting the runtime error when I do it? The debugger highlights this row of code: "erow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0)"

Comment: Whoops, missed that - you need a ,row at the end of that line. ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0) defines a cell, and erow wants the row number - returned by the .row property of the cell. So ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).Row

Comment: @HarassedDad Also, `xlUp` is an Enum with value `-4162`, but this code uses `x1Up` which is an undeclared variable, defaulting to `0`

Answer (score 0):

## No Object Variable Necessary

The End Parameter is **`xlUp`** not `x1Up`.

### Array Version

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SplitTourCommand_Click()

    Const cSheet As String = "Splits"

    Dim erow As Long
    Dim vnt As Variant

    ReDim vnt(1 To 1, 1 To 10) As String

    vnt(1, 1) = OriginalTourCode.Text
    vnt(1, 2) = OriginalStartDate.Text
    vnt(1, 3) = OriginalEndDate.Text
    vnt(1, 4) = NewTourCode1.Text
    vnt(1, 5) = NewStartDate1.Text
    vnt(1, 6) = NewEndDate1.Text
    vnt(1, 7) = NewTourCode2.Text
    vnt(1, 8) = NewStartDate2.Text
    vnt(1, 9) = NewEndDate2.Text
    vnt(1, 10) = ReasonForSplit.Text

    With Worksheets(cSheet)
        erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(erow, 1).Resize(, 10) = vnt
    End With

End Sub
```

### Range Version

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SplitTourCommand_Click()

    Const cSheet As String = "Splits"

    Dim erow As Long

    With Worksheets(cSheet)
        erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(erow, 1) = OriginalTourCode.Text
        .Cells(erow, 2) = OriginalStartDate.Text
        .Cells(erow, 3) = OriginalEndDate.Text
        .Cells(erow, 4) = NewTourCode1.Text
        .Cells(erow, 5) = NewStartDate1.Text
        .Cells(erow, 6) = NewEndDate1.Text
        .Cells(erow, 7) = NewTourCode2.Text
        .Cells(erow, 8) = NewStartDate2.Text
        .Cells(erow, 9) = NewEndDate2.Text
        .Cells(erow, 10) = ReasonForSplit.Text
    End With

End Sub
```